# I have i3-7100 ,12gb ram , 3TB HDD and a 120GB SSD

Tags: windows, windows-10, ssd, operating-systems, migration

Okay so I have i3-7100, 12gb ram, 3tb HDD and a 120GB SSD.

I want to migrate my os to my SSD, but for some reason my OS is 1.7TB lol https://gyazo.com/e8181ef47abcc70db85292ada8bb3fb3

and my SSD is probably 111.7 LOL

I really don't know how to just put my Windows OS over. I want all of my games and apps on the 3tb HDD and just the OS and drivers on the SSD.

Comment: Windows doesn't occupy 1.7TB, that's the size of the partition, which is still almost half empty.  With that much space filled, what it contains is mostly your stuff, and apparently backups.  Windows will have plenty of room to spare on a 120 GB SSD.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to migrate Windows selectively to the SSD, since obviously the
HDD is too large for the SSD.

You may try and use
[Paragon Migrate OS](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/migrate-os-to-ssd/#),
free for home use.

You need to have the two disks connected to the computer.
The tool will migrate Windows and will detect the disparity in sizes and
will try to do the job for you:

[image]

If this automatic action is not enough, you will need to install Windows from
scratch on the SSD, including your applications.